# How to return only one stock price?

Tags: r, dataset, quantmod, stock

[Initial Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM0Hf.png)I have over a thousand Stock Tickers, and corresponding IPO Dates. I would like use a loop to go through each stock ticker and find the Open Price for the IPO date. I can currently do this with quantmod. getSymbols(), but it downloads the entire data set, I can limit the data to a time frame, but it wont let me do this ex.

```css
getSymbols('AAPL', from = '2017-02-02', to = '2017-02-02')
```

For some reason this wont return the first price. It requires a bigger time frame, and I only care about the first Open Price. The end output would be to add a third column to my existing data frame, the third column would be the first price. I am really trying to avoid downloading thousands of Stocks data because then it would run forever. Any help downloading the first Open Price and then putting that price into a data frame for all of the Tickers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the initial date, but every stock IPO is different so im not sure how to write a function that could do date plus one day, if the IPO date is on the 31st how would that work? Also i will try to add a output table. @phiver

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't produced an example of your data, I've made my own. Next time please don't use a screenshot of the object. Use `dput()` instead.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)

getSymbols(c('AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'TSLA', 'FB'))
tickers <- data.frame(ticker = c('AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'TSLA', 'FB'),
                      date = sapply(mget(setdiff(ls(),"B")), function(x) as.character(index(x[1,]))))

tickers$open <- NA
tickers$date <- ymd(tickers$date)
```

In the above code I download data for a few stocks and get the first date of data and use that as an ipo date. I have made the dates into a date format using `lubridate`. This makes it easier to add dates, as you've said in the comment, this is impossible with characters. However, if it is formatted as a date, + 7 will take it to the next month if the date is on the last day of the month.

Code below is simple. I extract the ticker, which will be passed to the `getSymbols` argument in `getSymbols()`. The `ipo_date` will be passed to the `from` argument of `getSymbols()`. The `next_date` is 7 days from the ipo date, anything less than 7 days does not work.

I set `auto.assign` to `FALSE` so that `getSymbols()` does not save the object to the environment. This allows me to extract the first open price, which is always in the first row of the first column, hence the `[1, 1]` immediately after the `getSymbols()` call.

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(tickers)) {

  ticker <- as.character(tickers[i, 'ticker'])

  ipo_date <- as.character(tickers[i, 'date'])

  next_date <- as.character(tickers[i, 'date']+7)

  tickers[i, 'open'] <- getSymbols(ticker, from = ipo_date, to = next_date, 
                                   auto.assign = FALSE)[1,1]

}
```

Comment: I would love to add my data set in here but I am not sure how to add it in this post, I appreciate the answer! However the code "index(x[1,])))" returns the error "incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: You can just give a snapshot, if code works on a few lines, it will scale and work on the full data. That part of the code was just for me to create data to test my code on. This is why providing examples is important, makes the process smoother to avoid this back and forth, Use the second chunk. Also, what's the name of your object with the tickers and ipo dates?

Comment: Use ````dput(x[1:10, ])```` where ````x```` is the name of the object with your data. Then copy and paste the output in the console. Then paste that in your question

Comment: I tried running your code without changing it and me modifying it and the same error occurred for both, I have a screenshot at the beginning of the post and I think that's what your asking for, and they should all be strings

Comment: Use dput(x[1:10, ]) where x is the name of the object with your data. Then copy the output from the console. Then paste that in your question as an edit.

Comment: structure(list(`IPO Date` = c("7/9/2018", "9/21/2018", "6/30/2017", 
"9/28/2017", "9/12/2018", "8/1/2018", "4/3/2018", "6/19/2018", 
"6/29/2017", "9/28/2018"), `Stock Symbol` = c("1810", "FTCH", 
"DHER", "ROKU", "NIO", "CWK", "SPOT", "4385", "APRN", "FCH")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(1344L, 1899L), col = c("Closed Date Precision", "Closed Date Precision"
    ), expected = c("1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE", "1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE"
    ), actual = c("none", "none"), file = c("'

Comment: Comment was to big but i excluded the file on my computer where i read in a csv file

Comment: Edit your question to include that. Also give the name of the object. That way you will simply copy and paste the answer

Comment: ("'StockAnalysis/IPO-15-19.csv'", 
    "'StockAnalysis/IPO-15-19.csv'")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))) Object name is xy

Answer (score 1):

Some of your stocks are not American! This is problematic as Yahoo Finance uses a country extension for equity markets outside of America. For instance, there is not stock with a symbol of 1810 in America, so this returns an error. There are several outside of America, I chose the one from Hong Kong. To download this data, you need to be put .HK after the symbol for Hong Kong. For LSE (London), it's .L

Once I fixed this the code works. All tickers have their open price on IPO date. However, if these are in different currencies, I'm not sure how useful this is.

```r
xy <- data.frame(`IPO Date` = c("7/9/2018", "9/21/2018", "6/30/2017", "9/28/2017",
                                "9/12/2018", "8/1/2018", "4/3/2018", "6/19/2018",
                                "6/29/2017", "9/28/2018"), `Stock Symbol` = 
                                c("1810.HK", "FTCH", "DHER.DE", "ROKU", "NIO", 
                                  "CWK", "SPOT", "4385.T", "APRN", "FCH.L"))

colnames(xy) <- gsub('\\.', ' ', colnames(xy))

library(lubridate)
library(quantmod)

xy$`IPO Date` <- mdy(xy$`IPO Date`)
xy$`IPO Open Price` <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(xy)) {

  ticker <- as.character(xy[i, 'Stock Symbol'])

  ipo_date <- as.character(xy[i, 'IPO Date'])

  next_date <- as.character(xy[i, 'IPO Date']+7)

  xy[i, 'IPO Open Price'] <- getSymbols(ticker, from = ipo_date, to = next_date, 
                                   auto.assign = FALSE)[1,1]

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I think i will have to add the extra step to each non American Stock, but this helps a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to look up all of quantmods stock exchanges symbols or do you have to do it individually? @Mr.Rlover

Comment: The stock data from yahoo finance not quantmod, so no this is not an option with quantmod. https://help.yahoo.com/kb/exchanges-data-providers-yahoo-finance-sln2310.html has a list of country codes that yahoo uses. If you know the country that each stock in your list is in, you can write a Web scrapping script that matches the country in your list with the country in that table and gets the country code.